# PyTorch convert function for op 'pad' not implemented

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, coremltools

When I trying to convert model.ckpt to core ML model use coremltools I got this error:

```
  
  File "/Users/peterpan/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/ops.py", line 86, in convert_nodes
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op 'pad' not implemented.
```

Here is converting code:

```
   model: torch.nn.Module = make_training_model(train_config)
    state = torch.load(path, map_location=map_location)
    model.load_state_dict(state['state_dict'], strict=strict)
    model.on_load_checkpoint(state)
    model.eval()
   
    jit_model_wrapper = JITWrapper(model)
    image = torch.rand(1, 3, 120, 120)
    mask = torch.rand(1, 1, 120, 120)
    output = jit_model_wrapper(image, mask)

    device = torch.device("cpu")

    image = image.to(device)
    mask = mask.to(device)
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(jit_model_wrapper, (image, mask), strict=False).to(device)
    model1 = ct.convert(
        traced_model,
        source='pytorch',
        inputs=[ct.ImageType(name='image',shape=image.shape), ct.ImageType(name='mask',shape=mask.shape)]
    )
    model1.save("newmodel.mlmodel")
```

I'm newbie in python. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to `coremltools==6.0` fixed this problem for me

Answer (score -1):

downgrade torch version that solved this problem